# Autofilling attributes based on locations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, spatial-join, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon layer (admin boundaries); what I want is when I create a point inside any of the polygons, some attributes are auto filled in the point inherited from the polygon it is in.

I looked for similar questions, but one was using a deprecated plugin (Auto fill) which doesn't seem to work in QGIS 3.0 or later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

Since QGIS 3.16 you don't need a Plugin. You can use the new [overlay expressions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-contains): e.g. `overlay_within('polygonlayer',"polygonid")`.

First, install [refFunctions plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/).

Then open properties of your point layer and navigate to `fields`. Toggle `editing mode` on and create a `new field`. Now go to `attributes form`, select `your field` within available widgets *(eventually you need to reopen layer properties to get your new field beeing displayed)*, then on the right go to `default value` and fill it with the following expression: `geomwithin('polygonlayer','polygonid')`. Adjust it to your needs: Replace `'polygonlayer'` with the name of your polygonlayer and `'polygonid'` with the fieldname of the polygonlayer you want to get.

[image]

If you now create a new point, the field will be filled with the information from the polygonlayer you have specified.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you very much for taking the time, truly appreciate it.

Comment: Note that for the overlay expressions, an array_to_string is necessary, like this : 
array_to_string(overlay_within('polygonlayer',"polygonid"))

Answer (score 5):

You may try this expression with `aggregate()` function ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html)):

```
aggregate(
    layer:='Estados_brasileiro',
    aggregate:='max',
    expression:="uf",
    filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer. I see too many answers relying on refFunctions - an extra dependency, what if this project is opened by someone without the plugin? - when the inbuilt `aggregate()` function has been able to use spatial relations since the first release of QGIS 3.

Comment: @she_weeds Functions in refFunctions plugin probably will be QGIS core functions soon. [Reference 1](https://github.com/enricofer/refFunctions/issues/25), [Reference 2](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/145)

Comment: @Denilson Thank you for this answer as well.