# Automatically populating point layer with ID of polygon it intersects in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

I am using QGIS 3 and trying to populate a column of a point file that has rare species data. One of the attributes is a Wetland `"ID"` column. If any of my rare species points are within a wetland, I would like that column to have the Wetland `"ID"`. If it isn't in the Wetland, then that column would simply be blank.

I am not sure how to approach this or if it is possible. The alternative is to manually input this data, but the data set is large and we don't really have the resources to do this manually. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

Use this expression on the point layer:

```
overlay_within('wetland', id, filter:=category='wetland')[0]
```

- `wetland` is the name of the polygon layer
- `id` is the name of the wetland id
- `category` is the name of the field in the `wetland` layer containing the string `wetland`

[See the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-within) about the `overlay_within()` function.

*Here, points are labeled with the expression from above:*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way would be use the "Attributes Form" in the layer properties, and the Aggregate function.

1. Right-click the point layer that you want the automatic
   attributation assisgned to
2. Head to the "Attributes Form" menu, and select the Field that you
   want to assigned the label to.
3. You will see a "Defaults" option at the bottom of this window, where
   you can add a "default value" or expression.

Use the following expression:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='YOUR WETLAND LAYER NAME',
    aggregate:='concatenate',
    expression:="Field Name",
    filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    )
```

1. You will need to tick on "Apply default value on update" for the
   expression to work.

I got this expression from this answer: [Autofill attributes in QGIS based on locations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356990/autofill-attributes-in-qgis-based-on-locations) as well as the expression options for `aggregate()` function ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html)).

I tested this in QGIS 3.10